# Is there a constant value of the time constant RC

Tags: electric-circuits

Would it be correct to say that there is a definite, finite value of time constant in a Resistor- Capacitor circuit, i.e is there a constant value for RC ( where R is resistance and C is capacitance)

Comment: If R and C remain constant, then of course, their product will remain constant. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a definite RC time constant for any given resistor and capacitor.   There are also other time constants for real components, related to stray inductance, skin effect, and sometimes mechanical
resonances.

The as-marked R and C values are valid characterizations of the
physical objects only in a broad sense; no object is purely
a resistor or capacitor, though resistive and capacitive behavior
can be good approximations in 'normal' circumstances.